# Can a flyback diode work on the "ground" side of a transistor?

Tags: mosfet, flyback, snubber

In every flyback diode setup I see, the relay coils are on the drain side of the transistor (if my terminology is wrong, I mean the top), so the flyback diode sends current back toward the power source. I'm curious if it can also be setup like this, with the load and flyback on the "grounded" source side of the transistor. I think it should work, but I'm not sure. As an aside, how would I test this for myself?

[image: Diode on ground side of transistor]

Comment: The load should always be on the drain if you don't have a very good reason to put it on the source. That means using a PMOS instead of an NMOS in a situation like this.

Comment: "*As an aside, how would I test this for myself?*", like [this](http://tinyurl.com/yykuvqfu). You could use a PMOS instead of an NMOS with your design, but you're not gaining anything from that as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some misconceptions need to be corrected:

### 1. The flyback diode does not send current back to the power source.

The power source is irrelevant. The flyback diode gives the current in the inductor an "easy" path to continue to circulate through the inductor.

When current is interrupted in the inductance, it uses the energy stored in its magnetic field to continue to keep current flowing through it. So for a short time after the current is interrupted, think of it as a battery. The current flows in the same direction as before the interruption but the voltage across the inductor has reversed since it is now acting as a source and not a load. That voltage forward biases any diode in anti-parallel with it to give the current a path to flow. That voltage will be as high as necessary to keep the current flowing through the inductor. If the current path available is tough, it will be a very damaging high voltage to force the current through. If it's an easier path (like a diode with low forward voltage drop) then the voltage produced is less. Using that mindset, you should always be able to tell if flyback measures will work or not. The flyback diode gives the current IN the inductor a loop where it can continue to flow. The power source is irrelevant. So the diode in your circuit will work to suppress flyback voltage spikes, but...

### 2. Your circuit, as a whole, will not work. You cannot simply move the load from the "high-side" to the "low-side" like you just did.

The reason you see the coil on the drain side of the transistor is that the voltage DIFFERENCE that turns the MOSFET on is the voltage DIFFERENCE between the gate and source terminals. Which means that if the source terminal is not tied to a fixed potential (i.e. ground or power rail, depending on whether you are using an NMOS or PMOS) then the circuitry gets a lot more complicated since now the signal being sent to the gate must float on the MOSFET's source voltage.

This means, that as drawn, your circuit will not work but for reasons you don't yet realize. Suppose I apply 15V to the gate of M6 to turn it on, will it turn on? That offhand phrase is loaded in that it implies that the 15V being applied to the gate is *relative to ground*.

But the MOSFET cannot and does not care about the voltage at its gate relative to ground (how is it supposed to know what the voltage at ground is? None of its pins are connected to ground). It cares about the voltage at its gate relative to the the voltage at its source terminal.

The circuit you have drawn is a source follower (as long as when there is no floating gate drive, or a ground-referenced gate-drive voltage is applied that is less than \$ V4 + V_{gs_{th}} + V_{gs_{overdrive}}\$. Where \$V_{gs_{th}} + V_{gs_{overdrive}}\$ is just the voltage requires to fully turn on the MOSFET. It's not just \$V_{gs_{th}}\$ since that's the voltage where the MOSFET *barely* starts to conduct and is only useful for amplifiers, not switches.

Being a source follower, the voltage applied to the coil (or load) can only ever be a maximum of \$V4 - V_{gs_{th}}\$, rather than V4. That is a lot of voltage not being applied to the load and if the current levels are high enough, that is a lot of heat being dissipated in the MOSFET since it's not fully on.

This situation can be corrected in two ways:

1. Replace the NMOSFET with a PMOSFET. Since the PMOSFET requires it's source terminal to be connected to +V and your transistor's location in the circuit is right next to +V, that fixes the problem of a floating gate-source voltage.
2. Use floating gate driver circuitry to drive the NMOSFET gate with a voltage that floats (aka is relative to) the source-terminal. Often done in inverters and motor drives because NMOSFETs are cheaper, more efficient, and more available than PMOSFETs.

As mentioned by @Spehro Pefhany in the comments, the source follower in this situtation actually eliminates the need for a flyback diode. When NMOSFET gate is brought to 0V to try and turn things off, the reduction in current causes the coil to kick. This kick brings the source terminal voltage negative low enough to make which make Vgs positive enough to turn the NMOSFET back on, even if 0V is applied to the gate. In effect, the inductive kick forces the MOSFET on partially thereby slowing down the shut-off time of the MOSFET, preventing it from slamming off which would cause an even higher, potentially damaging inductive kick to occur. This would interfere in high speed switching circuits, however.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96944/discussion-on-answer-by-dknguyen-can-a-flyback-diode-work-on-the-ground-side-o).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that could work fine, provided you have accounted for the Vgs drop (threshold voltage) for the FET vs. the relay pull-in voltage. Otherwise, use low-side instead. For a small coil that’s on your board this is the easier choice.

Put the diode directly across the coil if possible to minimize the flyback current loop area, regardless of the switch method you choose.

Discussion:

NMOS on the high-side is the classic solenoid driver setup. NMOS offers better Rds(on) than PMOS for a given die size so it’s the preferred approach for big coils. But there’s a catch: you will need a high-side gate driver with a boost voltage to make it work with best efficiency. The boost driver lifts Vg high enough to turn the FET on fully.

Here’s a relevant piece about driving solenoids (and a semi-shameless plug for an MPS device): https://www.electronicdesign.com/industrial-automation/what-s-best-way-drive-solenoid

Another way to solve this problem is to use a load switch. This integrates the NMOS FET, charge pump and high-side gate drive all in one convenient IC. There are many good, inexpensive ones designed for USB and general power management.